# Image display from custom field

Tags: images, metabox

I am trying to display image from my custom meta box but cant make it:

function.php file:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'order_box' );
function order_box() {
add_meta_box( 'meta-box-id', 'My Custom Field', 'my_custom_field', 'post', 'normal', 'high' );
}
function my_custom_field(){ 
global $post;
$custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
$order=$custom["order"][0];
$image=$custom["image"][0];
?>
<label for="custom_field">Put Order:</label>
<input type="text" name="order" value="<?php echo $order; ?>" />
<label for="custom_field">Upload Image:</label>
<input type="file" name="image" />
<?php  
} 

 add_action('save_post', 'save_order');
 function save_order(){
 global $post;
 update_post_meta($post->ID, "order", $_POST["order"]);
 update_post_meta($post->ID, "image", $_POST["image"] );
 }
```

my template file where i want display the image:

```
<?php
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<h1><a href="<?php the_permalink();?> ">  <?php the_title(); ?></a> </h1>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php 
$custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
$image=$custom["image"][0];
$order=$custom["order"][0];
echo $order;
?>
//***  <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" /> 
<img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'image',true); ?>" 
    width=200 height=200 />
 endwhile;
```

here 'order' is displayed nicely but not image. print_r($custom) got something like this:

```
Array ( 
    [_edit_last] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) 
    [order] => Array ( [0] => 13 ) 
    [image] => Array ( [0] => coffee_star.jpg ) 
)
```

someone please help me to display the image in my template page. I am very new to wordpress. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `update_post_meta()` than also use `get_post_meta()` (see [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)) and not `get_post_custom`

```
$order = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'order', true );
$image = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'image', true );
```

And than check in your HTML source what your image tag looks like. I bet it will look like this:

```
<img src="coffee_star.jpg" />
```

What about the path to the image?? Save the complete path of the image, not only the filename.

Comment: yes you are right.. i'm getting `<img src="coffee_star.jpg" />` in my HTML code as the filename only not file path. Please tell me the way to get filepath for displaying the image..

Comment: How should I know where your images are stored? WordPress have a lot of functions (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/admin_url#Related) to create a path. Please read the codex for more informations.

Comment: thanks for ur reply.. i just found this but cant display the image. Would u please look into this: [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75713/display-image-after-uploading-through-meta-box]

Comment: $image = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'image', true )['guid'];